# Using color in a style is not working in designer, but works in runtime

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I define a color

```
<Color x:Key="MyBlackColor">#000000</Color>
```

I use it in a style

```
<Style x:Key="PageHeaderStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="72" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="22,0,0,12"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MyBlackColor}"/>
</Style>
```

It works fine in a runtime (text is black), but in designer foreground is white.

Same in Blend. When i'm clicking "go to source" it jumps directly to the line Value="{StaticResource MyBlackColor}", but the foreground is white.

Any ideas, why?

Comment: Are you using style file ??

Comment: Yep, it is in a separate file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Foreground` is a `Brush` try using `SolidColorBrush` with your resource as a color:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground">
   <Setter.Value>
      <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource MyBlackColor}"/>
   </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can define your `Color` like you do;

```
<Color x:Key="MyBlackColor">#FF000000</Color>
```

then specify it as `Brush` right after.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ActualBlackColorForeground"
                 x:Name="ActualBlackColorForeground"
                 Color="{StaticResource MyBlackColor}" />
```

then plop it wherever whenever.

```
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ActualBlackColorForeground}"/>
```

and you should be good if you want to use it as a global resource. Hope this helps.